# Encapsulation: The field is not visible?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I have written a small program to understand Encapsulation and access method.
The code is :

```
package practise;

public class EncapTest {

    private String name;
    String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

---

```
package practise;

public class RunEncap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EncapTest encapObj = new EncapTest();

        encapObj.setName("Prabh");
        encapObj.surname = "Rana";

        System.out.println("Name :" + encapObj.getName());
        System.out.println("Surname :" + encapObj.surname);
    }


}
```

---

Now if i create another package "practise2" and use import and try to create object of "EncapTest", I am able to access the variable name, but when i am trying to access surname, it shows error that the field surname is not visible..

```
package practise2;

import practise.EncapTest;

public class Runencap2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EncapTest encapObj = new EncapTest();

        encapObj.setName("Prabh");
        encapObj.surname = "Rana";     // <<<<getting error here

        System.out.println("Name :" + encapObj.getName());
        System.out.println("Surname :" + encapObj.surname);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to read/understand access specifiers in java (public,private, protected and default). Understanding these concepts will itself answer your question.

In the example above, you have declared instance variable "surname" with default access (implicit access specifier used if not specified as public, private or protected). Default access only allows you to make a variable/method accessible only within the same package. As a result you are able to access it in the class "RunEncap", but not in "Runencap2" as the variable is not visible to other packages. Moreover, as a good programming practice it is advisable to declare variables as private and write getter/setter methods to access them.

Here is a sample link you can refer to understand access specifiers - http://www.aoiblog.com/java-access-specifier/

Answer (score 3):

Your `surname` field has default (package-private) access level, it means that this field visible only for classes, which declared in same package.

```
String surname; // access level implicitly sets to package-private
```

There are four access levels in Java:

- public
- protected
- package-private (no explicit modifier)
- private

If your class member has no explicit modifier - it automatically sets to package-private. It's fully [described](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) in official tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your two classes are in different packages. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only *within its own package* (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)
>
> At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Answer (score 0):

Sunilkumar from vmoksha

PLease go to deeper navigation it will work
  Create the object for the class and again create setter/getter for the object created class